# How to not call a function inside another function in Unit test Dart?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I want to not call a few function calls that are inside a function that I am testing. I am new to testing. Since I am using `SetUpALL((){});` to create a test suitable case instead of using the function.

main file:

```
class A{

 Future<void> function_1 () async {
   await another_function_1 // want to igonre this function in test.
 }

}
```

test file:

```
void main {
 setUpAll((){
 // statements.
 });
 group('tests',(
   test('test 1',(){

     A().function1(); // calling the function here for testing.

   });
 ){
});

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of "Designing Testable Classes".  You'll probably need to refactor this method to extract a testable part of the operations.  Also, learn about Mockito to stub out dependent classes with your own behavior.

Comment: I did use MockIto to create a class that extends  the `Mock`  class and implements the class which includes the function `another_function()` which I want to exclude. But I am confused on how to use the `when(mockedClass().another_function()).thenAnswer((innvioation){// Statements That I want to execute instead});` to change the behaviour

Comment: Can you tell if I am going in the right direction by using `.thenAnswer((innvocation)=>null);` or is there something else that I have to learn or refer to ?